What is this banging noise in radiator pipe?
When my central heating system comes on I get a loud banging noise in one radiator. It can happen multiple times during the first 5 - 10 minutes, and also happens when the radiator is going off.
It is worse when the temperature is lower.
It's a problem because it wakes me up.
The TRV and valve have been replaced twice but that has not had any effect. I have a combi-boiler.
Short video clip: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1is1JMCS7iTALXkdfPnHdMNmJRYn6g5NI/view
You may need to turn the sound up.
